# Non-Parametric Statistics: Probability of Median and Order Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics, median

Let $X_1, ... , X_n$ be a random sample from a continuous distribution F. Let $\theta$ be the median of F. Using normal approximation, calculate the probability P($X_{(3)} \leq \theta \leq X_{(n-2)}$).

[Probability of Median from a continuous distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52032/probability-of-median-from-a-continuous-distribution?rq=1)

This one is extremely similar and I think the answer would either be $$\frac{6}{2^n}$$ or $${n \choose 6} * (\frac{1}{2})^n$$ according to the logic given in the previous question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Why do you think either of these follows the logic of the other post?